# Flutter show double bottomsheet type design

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to know what type of widget is this in flutter or how can create this. I know this question is irrelevant but I didn't find this so that's why I need to ask

[image]

You can see it's showing a round bottom sheet type thing and in the background show one more rounded bottom sheet. These types of things I see in every app now and need to design something similar any help how can I achieve this?

Comment: have you found any solution yet? i need to make something similar

Answer (score 1):

try [modal_bottom_sheet](https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet):

```
showCupertinoModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => Container(),
)
```